# Angular.js set input field value using ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make an input that formats currency using angular.js, preferably when focus is lost. Here's what I have so far

```
<div layout-fill>
    <md-input-container layout-fill currency class="number-range">
        <input placeholder="From"
               type="text"
               name="from"
               precision="{{rangeController.precision}}"
               ng-blur="pls = {{pls | currency}}"
               ng-model="pls"/>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

where precision always evaluates to `2`. I know this is wrong (because it isn't working), but I can't find anything in the documentation about this, and everything I google talks about huge JQuery libraries that can format in any of a hundred different international currencies. I want to use neither JQuery, nor any external code and this seems pretty simple, so I can't figure out why no one has ever tried to do it.

Comment: For starters, ng-blur="$scope.pls = {{pls | currency}}" is wrong. You either want ng-blur="pls = {{pls | currency}}" , or ng-blur="someFunction()" where you use $filter to apply that filter to $scope.pls.    To clarify, you should never be using "$scope" anywhere in your html. Assuming you aren't using controllerAsSyntax, all applicable variables will automatically be referenced/evaluated on the $scope object.

Comment: Oh I've tried every combination of using `$scope` and not, that was just the current incarnation. I've updated the question to the first of the formats you indicated, and can confirm that the issue still exists, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8mT3EA?p=preview) does what you're asking.  It uses this directive:

```
   .directive('blurToCurrency', function($filter){
  return {
    scope: {
      amount  : '='
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs){
      el.val($filter('currency')(scope.amount));

      el.bind('focus', function(){
        el.val(scope.amount);
      });

      el.bind('input', function(){
        scope.amount = el.val();
        scope.$apply();
      });

      el.bind('blur', function(){
        el.val($filter('currency')(scope.amount));
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: The problem with solutions like this is that I'm using typescript, which is why I was trying to get an inline solution so that I don't have to mess with a conversion I don't understand. Thanks though!